# How to package my application as multiple archives?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've got an application and I'd like to deliver it as a set of ZIP or RPM (or even fat JAR) archives by defining components.

For instance, I'd like a task that builds a ZIP archive for my application containing all built jars, and another archive with all dependencies.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sbt-1.2` and [`sbt-native-packager-1.x`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/), you can achieve that.

In a multi-project build, `sbt-native-packager` adds a task, `Universal / packageBin`, which builds a ZIP archive for your application, with a nice shell script to define its classpath. It works like a charm:

```scala
// in your (sub)project definition (a .sbt file, anyone)
lazy val MySubProject1 = (project in file("MySubProject1"))
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

This allows you to:

```
sbt:MyProject> project MySubProject1
sbt:MySubProject1> universal:packageBin
[...]
  adding: lib/
  adding: lib/MySubProject2-0.1.0.jar
  adding: lib/MySubProject1-0.1.0.jar
  adding: lib/org.apache.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.jar
[...]
  adding: bin/
  adding: bin/MySubProject1
  adding: bin/MySubProject1.bat
[success] [...]
^D
$ unzip -l target/universal/MySubProject1.zip # list archive content :)
[...]
```

---

Ok, now we want to output **two** ZIP archives: one for **your** jars (the ones sbt built) and one for **their** jars (the ones sbt downloaded). It's not as easy, but achievable.

In order to organize things, we'll define some of the code in scala files. Assume the following project hierarchy:

```
MyProject              |
├── build.sbt          | Define all that is not defined in modules.sbt
├── modules.sbt        | Defile all (sub)projects
├── project/           |
│   ├── Settings.scala | Define settings to apply to (sub)projects
│   └── Deps.scala     | Define dependencies
├── MySubProject1/     | This is the subproject you will package
│   └── src/           |
├── ...                | Some of those subprojects are dependencies to MuSubProject1
└── MySubProjectn/     | 
    └── src/           |
```

#### `modules.sbt`: apply our packaging settings to MySubProject1

```scala
lazy val MySubProject1 = (project in file("MySubProject1"))
  .settings(
    name := "AwesomeApp",
    Settings.Common ++ Settings.Package, // this is here (Settings.Package) that magic operates
    libraryDependencies ++= Deps.Spark,
  )
  .dependsOn(MySubProject2)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging) // This is still needed
```

#### `project/Settings.scala`: define the settings needed for packaging

From a simple scala object, we'll expand our packaging strategy

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

// additional imports (0/)

object Settings {
  lazy val Common = Seq(
    version := "0.1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    // other settings
  )

  // <packaging strategy> (1/, 2/ & 3/)
}
```

0/ Add some imports

```scala
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.UniversalPlugin.autoImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.universal.Archives.makeNativeZip
```

1/ Add one configuration per target archive

```scala
  val Application  = config("application")
  val Dependencies = config("dependencies")
```

2/ Define our partitioning (which file goes in which configuration)

```scala
  //! @brief Return the configuration this file is into.
  private[this] def configOf(mapping: (File, String)): Configuration = mapping match {
    case (file, _) =>
      if (file.getPath() contains "/cache/") Dependencies // this depends on **your** context and should be improved
      else Application
  }

  //! @brief Return a file filter for this configuration to apply with @c filter on a file mapping.
  private[this] def filterOf(conf: Configuration): ((File, String)) => Boolean = {
    mapping: (File, String) => configOf(mapping) == conf
  }
```

3/ Create the ZIP archive for each configuration

```scala
  //! @brief Define the task packageBin for this configuration.
  private[this] def packageDefinition(conf: Configuration): Setting[Task[File]] = {
    conf / packageBin := {
      // TODO add JavaAppPackaging plugin to the project here, but how? See `thisProject.value.autoPlugins`?
      val targets = (Universal / mappings).value filter filterOf(conf)
      makeNativeZip(target.value, s"${packageName.value}-${conf.name}", targets, None, Nil)
    }
  }

   /**
    * @brief Add packaging configuration to a project.
    *
    * Apply with:
    * @code
        lazy val subproject = (project in file ("directory")).settings(
          name := "MyAwesomeSubProject",
          Settings.Package,
        ).enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
    * @endcode
    */
  def Package = Seq(
    maintainer := "YSC@example.com",
    packageName := s"${name.value}",

    packageDefinition(Application),
    packageDefinition(Dependencies),
  )
```

This is it! You can now apply the `application:packageBin` and `dependencies:packageBin` on your subproject to generate respectively `AwesomeApp-application.zip` and `AwesomeApp-dependencies.zip`.

Enjoy!